# In python, how do I make a raw_input of a list from one number?

Tags: python, list, raw-input

I need some code that allows a user to input a number (ie. 5) that creates a list of all the numbers leading up to that number excluding zero (ie. [1,2,3,4,5])

Comment: what's the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> range(1,int(raw_input('Number: '))+1)
Number: 5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: How do I get that to include the original number? In this case 5.

Comment: Refresh your browser. I edited the original answer

Answer (score 0):

```
In [11]: L = range(1, int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))+1)
Enter a number: 5

In [12]: L
Out[12]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
     try:
        v = int(raw_input('Number: '))
     except:
        print 'Invalid number!!'
     else:
        print range(1,v)
        break
```

This will prevent the user from inputing an invalid number.